# Promise.all() method doesn't resolve to a value

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

The following code resolves to `Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}` in the last then handler.

Though when logging the array with promises to the console, each has status `resolved` and all the requests are fulfilled.

```
MusicService
  .getArtists()
  .then((res) => {
     let arr = res.filter((a) => {
        return a.id.length;
     });
     return Promise.all(arr.map(function(a) {
        return fetch(`//service.com/api/artist/${a.id}`);
     }));
   })
   .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
   });
```

So what am I missing to get this working?

Comment: What happens if you have a fail callback in any of those `then`s? Or a `catch`?

Comment: @NielsSteenbeek that is how promises work. in a promise you can return a promise and it will get chained in the promise chain.

Comment: "The following code resolves to `Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}` in the last then handler." Yeah, and what did you expect?

Comment: @Neal tried adding catch handler, but it doesn't enter there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW, this can be reduced to:

```
MusicService
  .getArtists()
  .then(res => Promise.all(
    res
      .filter(a => a.id.length > 0)
      .map(a => fetch(`//service.com/api/artist/${a.id}`))
    )
  )
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res);
  });
```

In the last callback, `res` would be an array of `fetch()` results, it can't be anything else.

Comment: Yes, it has to be an array, but still all I get is this line, that promise is pending.

Comment: If I test this exaxt code with mockup `getArtists()` and `fetch()` functions that return promises, then I get an array of values in the callback. Are you super double sure that a) you have exactly this code (and not something subtly different) and b) your fetch function actually returns promises for values (and not something subtly different)?

Comment: I double checked everything and I still can't figure out what's going wrong. Anyway, thanks for the effort.

Comment: Debugging goes both ways. Start from this, write these few lines and into a small JS file. Mock all missing functions. Extend the code bit by bit by yanking your own code back in until it breaks.

Comment: switched from the SystemJS to the Webpack and it started to work like a charm. Yet it's not clear to me why wasn't it working from the very beginning.

Comment: I'm sure there's a reason you can find if you dig long enough.

Comment: @danny Check out https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector for an interactive debugger for node that might help you with this.